# How to set multiple domains to app url laravel

Tags: laravel

i have some domains that parked on one laravel base system, ex:

- domain1.com
- domain2.com
- domain3.com

app_url in .env set to **domain1.com**

When open domain2.com or domain3.com all of files & images open with url domain1.com. I want to when domain2.com open then files & images load in domain2.com.

How?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to load different .env file for multiple domain in single laravel app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50876296/how-to-load-different-env-file-for-multiple-domain-in-single-laravel-app)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved!

in config/filesystems.php replace

```
    'public' => [
        'url' => env('APP_URL').'/uploads',
    ],
```

with

```
    'public' => [
        'url' => config('app.url').'/uploads',
    ],
```

then set

```
config(['app.url' => request()->getSchemeAndHttpHost()]);
```

in app/Providers/AppServiceProvider.php or every where is needed!